# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que las barras de un grafico bar3d de matplotlib salgan cortadas?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Tengo un problema con el gráfico bar3d de la librería matplotlib, la barra sale cortada, no llega al numero que debería en el eje Z. He buscado en varios lados pero no logro llegar a la solución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la barra roja deberia estar sobre el 70%, la última barra debe sobrepasar el 60% la amarrilla debe llegar casi al 50% y así. A continuación dejo el código utilizado:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

# Instrucciones para graficar 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12)) ## creamos la figura
fig.set_size_inches(16,10)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111 , projection = '3d') ## agrandamos el plano

posicion_x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
posicion_y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
posicion_z = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
###########
###
dx = np.ones(5)
dy = np.ones(5)
dz = [71, 56, 63, 47, 60]

## Nombre filas
nombre_filas = [124, 204, 295, 305, 704]

## Nombre Columnas
nombre_columnas = ['cosa1','cosa2','cosa3','cosa4','cosa5']

### Color
cs = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'c'] 

ax.bar3d(posicion_x, posicion_y, posicion_z, dx, dy, dz, color= cs, alpha = 0.5)

ticksx = np.arange(0.5, 5, 1)
plt.xticks(ticksx, nombre_filas)

ticksy = np.arange(0.5, 5, 1)
plt.yticks(ticksy, nombre_columnas, rotation = 0, verticalalignment='baseline',
                   horizontalalignment='left')                 

ax.set_xlabel('Total personas')
ax.set_zlabel('% personas')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente es un problema de perspectiva.

Si te fijas bien en la imagen que obtienes, el "suelo" no está en Z=0, sino un pelín por debajo, de modo que las columnas "flotan" un poco, pero esto no debería ser problema porque aún así su altura habría de ser la correcta.

Pero es que además de flotar un poco, no están "pegadas a la pared". Hay una distancia entre la parte de atrás de la columna y la pared donde se leen los valores del eje Z.

En la siguiente figura intento señalar estos problemas:

[image: Problemas]

Creo que es esa "distancia a la pared" la que, debido a la perspectiva, hace que la parte superior de la columna aparezca por debajo de de la marca de 60, aunque su altura sea 60.

Ese gap entre columnas y paredes puede ajustarse jugando con `xlim` y con `ylim`. En cambio el hecho de que z=0 no esté "a ras de suelo" no he podido cambiarlo, pese a fijar un `zlim`.

No obstante la figura ya sale más próxima a lo que buscas, con sólo añadir al final, antes del `plt.show()`:

```
ax.set_xlim(0.1, None)
ax.set_ylim(0, 4.9)
ax.set_zlim(0, 75)
```

[image: Resultado]

**PS** Las gráficas en 3D son más difíciles de leer. Si lo que importa es la información y no el aspecto, esta gráfica en particular sería mucho mejor en 2D pues a fin de cuentas la información que muestra es bidimensional.